# Array String Processing

Tags: java, arrays

How would I make a program that would test if the characters of one array could spell another word?
Like if I were to receive an array with the word Trumpet and an array with the word pet. The character can be in any order in the array.  How could I test in a boolean method to see if the characters in trumpet could spell pet?

Comment: Sort the characters of both `String`(s) into lexical order, then you could use `contains()` or `String.indexOf(String) > -1`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What research or coding have you tried? We are not here to write programs for you

Comment: Sounds like a University assignment....

Comment: @Elliot I am not sure this would work. Take for example cabab and abc. Sorting them would give you aabbc and abc but abc is not contained in aabbc

Comment: @benji OP didn't say they had to be in original order. Of course, it's possible you're right - the question is ambiguous. But the letters `abc` are certainly in `aabbc`. And then you posted my comment as an answer, so clearly you agree with me.

Comment: @Elliot I posted my answer at the same time you posted your comment. I agree that sorting is the first step. I just think that then we should scan both arrays at the same time rather than use indexOf or contains because it wouldn't work for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to sort the 2 arrays and then iterate over them in parallel and see that all the characters in the smaller array exist in the bigger array